# WPF C# TextBlock alignment doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I am working on a small project in WPF and I have to work only in C#, but there is few confusing things. Alignment doesn't seem to work at all with some elements, especially `TextBlock`. Sometimes `TextAlignment` works, but that's all. I am not sure what is wrong. Part of code I use:

```
public static Canvas buttonRightPanelTile(this Canvas tile)
    {
        tile.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,50,50,50));
        tile.Height = 100;
        tile.Width = 100;

        TextBlock title = new TextBlock();
        title.Text = "Další\nfunkce";
        title.FontSize = Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 36;
        title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        title.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        title.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        title.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

        tile.Children.Add(title);


        return tile;
    }
```

There are three alignments and non of them affects the text position in tile. Tile itself is located in grid cell and is aligned properly.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Canvas is not a suitable panel for dynamic size layouts***. It doesn't adhere to the alignments.

It should be used for only fixed-size layouts. For ***dynamic layouts you should use Grid***.

To align control on Canvas you have to set Top and Left of control to some absolute positions like:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(title, tile.ActualWidth / 2);
Canvas.SetTop(title, tile.ActualHeight / 2);
```

*Add some offsets to calculation in case needed to align control in centre of canvas as per your convenience.*